# Are standard 20A receptacles a NFPA 58 ignition source?

Tags: electrical, gas

This is to determine if a 10 foot distance to the propane tank fill port is required.

[image: NFPA 58 definition of ignition source]

Thanks.

Comment: Fantastic. I see a nice spark everytime I plug in my popcorn popper.

Comment: I get that - but there are some key nuances in the code - 10 foot from fill port if it is an ignition source - where the code implies that's things like a A/C compressor motor or a direct vent intake / exhaust.  By itself, an outlet sitting there is not an ignition source.  No diagram I can find references an outlet.

Comment: @HouseDiY -- how big is the propane tank in question?

Comment: Propane tank is 1000 gal.

Answer (score 1):

### This doesn't apply to you, but...

As of the 2017 edition (with no sign of changes in 2020), NFPA 58 Table 6.25.2.2 sets a 15' (not 10'!) distance between unclassified (ordinary location/non-ignitionproof) electrical equipment and the filling ports of containers over 1000lb water capacity.  However, NFPA 58 6.25.2.4 waives that requirement for commercial and residential installations:

> **6.25.2.4** The provisions of 6.25.2.2 shall not apply to fixed
> electrical equipment at residential or commercial installations
> of LP-Gas systems or to systems covered by Section 6.26.

Personally, though, I would keep receptacles out of the 15' radius around the fill port anyway; this is a mitigation against the risk of someone plugging in unrated *portable* electrical equipment that could serve as an ignition source in its own right, though.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, thanks.  My read of 'fixed electrical equipment' would be a lamp socket hardwired,  no switch. Or even better hardwired LED light, no socket, no way to spark,  Is there a broader read to receptacles  and might you have a reference?

Comment: @HouseDiY -- the actual receptacle is fixed, no? (unless it's on a pendant, that is)